When does $x\ln f(x)$ become convex?
When a function $f>0$ is defined on $x\geq 0$, I would like to know the conditions for $F(x)=x\ln f(x)$ to be convex.
Naively, $f$ being convex looks sufficient, but it is not true even if $f$ is monotonically increasing. Since $F''$ includes a term proportional to $2f(x)-xf'(x)$, which can be arbitrarily negative by discontinuously changing the slope. For example, connecting $f(x)=x+1$ and $f(x)=10(x-1)+2$ at $x=1$ spoils the convexity of $F$ (see the attached figure). So, the differentiability of $f$ seems reasonable to impose.
We also observe that when $f(x)=e^{a+b/x}$  with constants $a,b$, $F(x)$ reads $ax+b$, which is the "weakest" convex function.
Now $f(x)$ is convex but monotonically decreasing. $1/x$ is also such a function, but it gives the concave function $F(x)=-x\ln x$.
Then, what guarantees the convexity of $x\ln f(x)$? It looks similar to the logarithmic convexity, but we could not find any useful connection. 

$x\ln(10(x-1)+2)$ is already not convex, so I don't understand the point of splicing it with another function.
